# Where are there defined objects between gerbes and bundle gerbes?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gerbes

Consider a special kind of/something like a gerbe where there is first given local trivialization data with equivalence over 2-fold overlaps but not isomorphism.
Does this exist in the literature?

Comment: Something like a locally constant sheaf of categories?  I would say this is exactly what a gerbe is meant to encode.  Maybe I am misunderstanding though?

Comment: My impression is that gerbes do not have to have a local structure in the sense of one on open sets of a cover but only on the intersections - do I misread?

Comment: I always interpreted gerbes as being sheaves/stacks of groupoids, which locally look like BG x U, where U is the trivializing open subset and G is the group banding the gerbe. As BG is just pt/G, there is no datum to be given on single elements of an open cover, but only on double overlaps, with compatibilities on triple intersections.

Comment: @Jim the information on two-fold overlaps only (as in bundle gerbes) correspond to transition functions valued in the moduli stack of line bundles. The sort of structure that is locally trivialised and related on overlaps up to equivalence is necessarily category-theoretic, for example a differentiable stack.